# How to install ASUS' AI Suite II program?

Tags: 11.10, installation, asus

I'm unable to install the "AMD A75 FCH Chipset Support DVD Rev.887.01" installation disk include with my Asus F1A75-M PRO motherboard. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit. I've tried using the program "Wine Windows Program Loader" to run the disk, with success but when I try to install the ASUS AI Suite II program I receive a message saying "load AsIo error". Asked for support from ASUS directly but they simply replied that they don't support Linux OS'. The AI Suite II program is the only thing I'm interested in on the disk.

Comment: Can you add a link to the program description? What does it do?

Comment: Good luck installing Windows drivers on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that this program will work in any form on Linux, even with wine, as it is probably too low level. You will only be able to use it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Wanna help?

I submitted new WineGQ AppDB entry: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13833

Please get full WineHQ logs; Open new issue and link to this one .. .additionaly you can vote. It would be much appreciarted contribution :)

Oh - thanks for actually making this post :) Glad to have someone brave enough to try such tools on *nix :) Kudos, mate!